# What does git filter-branch with no arguments do?

Tags: git

What does `git filter-branch` with no arguments do?

I ran this on my repo accidentally hitting enter prematurely.

Comment: After twenty-five minutes...
`Rewrite <sha1> (5019/8411)`

Comment: From the documentation: "f you specify no filters, the commits will be recommitted without any changes, which would normally have no effect. Nevertheless, this may be useful in the future for compensating for some Git bugs or such, therefore such a usage is permitted."

Comment: That said, I don't know if it changes the sha1's, but I think it does.

Comment: @MicroVirus: the new (copied) commits have SHA-1s computed from their contents.  If the contents exactly match the original (pre-copy) contents, the SHA-1s will match too.  That's normally the case, but we've come across at least one interesting i18n case where commit text gets converted from one encoding to another, so that a no-filter filter-branch modifies IDs.  (Also, filter-branch will apply grafts.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. It seemed to calculate the hashes and found no change.

Answer (score 0):

Filter-branch inspects and does any needed rewriting of the commits output by a `git rev-list` fed the arguments it passes along.  With no arguments to pass along, rev-list uses HEAD, your current checkout.

Along with any modifications you specify on the command line, filter-branch also bakes in local overrides from `.git/info/grafts` and `git replace`.

So to orphan the current checkout you can `git rev-parse @ >.git/info/grafts; git filter-branch`

Answer (score 0):

This is used for graft, as mentioned in [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

> To set a commit (which typically is at the tip of another history) to be the parent of the current initial commit, in order to paste the other history behind the current history:

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p <graft-id>/"' HEAD
```

That will be faster with git 2.6.4 or git 2.7 (Dec. 2015)

See [commit 348d4f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/348d4f2fc5d3c4f7ba47079b96676b4e2dd831fc) (06 Nov 2015) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2e5adec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e5adec97a65ce8c2c803b9e1cbb1c0d067e7e47), 04 Dec 2015)</sup>

> ### `filter-branch`: skip index read/write when possible
>
> If the user specifies an index filter but not a tree filter, `filter-branch` cleverly avoids checking out the tree entirely.
>   But we don't do the next level of optimization: if you have no index or tree filter, we do not need to read the index at all.
>
> This can greatly speed up cases where we are only **changing the commit objects (e.g., cementing a graft into place)**.
>   Here are numbers from the newly-added perf test:

```
Test                  HEAD^              HEAD
---------------------------------------------------------------
7000.2: noop filter   13.81(4.95+0.83)   5.43(0.42+0.43) -60.7%
```